# How does the value of a pointer (memory address) change according to size of increments?

Tags: c

When I have a pointer in C and print it out using %x in printf I would receive something like this: 924752f7

Now if I increment the pointer by the size of a char, like so:

```
pointer += sizeof(char)
```

How come I get back 924752fb? If a char is one byte (8 bits), wouldn't it only increment it by one address and the new value after incrementing would be: 924752f8?

Comment: Are you actually writing `sizeof(char)` or are you instead using `sizeof 'x'` for some character `x`?  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Pointer declared as `datatype *p;` increments by multiples of `sizeof(datatype)` bytes, not by one byte.

Comment: What is the type of the pointer? It would help if you can show a [short complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: How is `pointer` declared?

Comment: Look up "pointer arithmetic".

Comment: There is pretty much never a time where it would make sense to allow incrementing a pointer by a custom amount of bytes so C helps you out and increments by `n * sizeof(ptr[0])`.

Comment: `pointer += sizeof...` is ALWAYS wrong. Pointers must a have a type, and adding 1 to a pointer advances by the size of that type. Let's say the pointer is type `int*`. Since sizeof(char) is 1 by definition, `pointer + sizeof(char)` is the same as `pointer + 1`, which makes it point to the next `int`, probably 4 bytes away, but confuses the person reading the code into thinking its only advancing one byte.

Comment: Pointer is declared as and int*

Comment: Ahh I understand now thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you solved your problem, but in future, it's safer to print pointer values using `%p`, not `%x`.  (You'll get fewer surprises that way, if you're on a machine where pointers are not the same size as ints.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sizeof(char) is   1 so you are adding ‘1’ to your ‘pointer’  and pointer points to the next location. But that next location depends on the type of your pointer or type of variable your pointer is pointing to . It looks like it is pointing to something that has 4 bytes in length. Suppose your pointer is declared like this

```
char * ptr
```

Print statement indicates that before the addition ptr is pointing to address 0x2000

```
   ptr = ptr+sizeof(char)
```

After the addition pointer will be pointing to 0x2001.

```
int * ptr
```

In this if ptr is pointing to address 0x2000 before addition

```
ptr = ptr+sizeof(char)
```

After the addition pointer will be pointing to 0x2004.
(here the assumption is int is 4 bytes not a short int)